# How to clean up "old" views using sap.m.routing.Router

Tags: sapui5

With routing/routes defined in the manifest.json and using Router.navTo() to change the hash and the content of the target App control, I noticed that the "old" views and controllers are still hanging around and listening to events (e.g. performing binding updates for controls that are no longer visible on the stage).

I (wrongly) assumed that the router would clean these views/controls up for me - what is the recommended way doing so?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. Before calling oRouter.navTo(...) you can call unbind. To give you an example you could check [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/demokit/tutorial/worklist/07/webapp/controller/Object.controller.js). There you can find the following line of code inside the onNavBack handler:

```
this.getView().unbindElement();
```

unbindElement() is called because previously bindElement(...) was called in the same controller. So just make sure to use bind/unbind combination before oRouter.navTo()...